# Software for visualizing database schema from existing SQLite database

Tags: database, sql, sqlite

Dear Stackexchange Community,

my little problem looks like followed:
I have an existing SQLite3 Database with 15 Tables and I am looking for a tool that automatically creates me a Visualisation of the Schemas of all Tables.

I hope one of you has experience with that and can help me out.

Greetings

Jan